# Я не могу отправить Class "User" из MainActivity в DetailActivity

Tags: java, android-intent

```
{MainActivity}

void initViews(){
        Button b_detail = findViewById(R.id.b_detail);
        b_detail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                Cast cast = new Cast(14, "Zarifjon");
                intent.putExtra("cast", (Parcelable) cast);
                passObject(cast);
            }
        });
    }

    void passObject(Cast cast){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("cast", (Parcelable) cast);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

{DetailActivity}

void initViews(){

        TextView tv_detail = findViewById(R.id.tv_detail);
        tv_detail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
       });
        Cast cast = (Cast)getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("cast");
        Log.d(TAG, cast.toString());

        tv_detail.setText(cast.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MainActivity:

```
User user = new User("Name", "Age");
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("user", user);
startActivity(intent);
```

DetailActivity:

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
    User user = (User) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("user");
}
```